# matlab function limit NaN value

Tags: matlab, math, limit

I want to calculate limit of function in matlab. However in result I receive the value "NaN" (Not-a-Number). What I am supposed to do to get an answer in the form "= n"?

```
syms x n
lt=limit((x+1)^n-1/x)
```

Comment: Well the limit of your function, as x->0, does not exist, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function plotted for n=1. `n` is definitely not the limit. The function returns the correct value.

[image]

Comment: @user3224596 Note that you could compute `limit((x+1)^n-1/x,x,0,'left')` (which gives `inf`) or `limit((x+1)^n-1/x,x,0,'right')` (which gives `-inf`)